# Bitwise operators:- Ball, carrot, ampersand, tilde

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, ampersand, tilde

I want the **step by step explanation** of the following code:

```
print(1 | 0 ^ 1 & ~0)
```

I tried with the output bit (output with  first and second bit) and **got the answer as 0**. The tilde function got me hooked up for some time I found it a bit hard. **The answer is 1**.

Comment: Make sure you understand the precedence of the various operators which are described here:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: I would appreciate if you selected an answer since I and another contributor have sufficiently answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First you must understand what each operator does

`|` - Bitwise OR: Returns `True` (`1`) if either of its operands is 1. e.g.

`1 | 0 == True`

`&` - Bitwise AND: Returns `True` if both of its operands are 1. e.g.

`0 & 1 == False`

`^` - Bitwise XOR: Returns `True` if only one of its operands is 1. e.g.

`0 ^ 1 == True`

`~` - Bitwise NOT: Flips the bit of its operand.

edit: As noted by Daniel Martin, **In Python specifically**, it flips *all* of the bits of an arbitrary integer. The formula would be `~x == -x - 1` e.g.

`~0 == -1`

### Then you must understand the order of bitwise operations

In order of precedence:

`~` -> `&` -> `^` -> `|`

### Solving the expression in that order

1. `1 | 0 ^ 1 & ~0  == 1 | 0 ^ 1 & -1` - `~` is applied first
2. `1 | 0 ^ 1 & -1  == 1 | 0 ^ 1`     - `&` is applied second
3. `1 | 0 ^ 1       == 1 | 1`         - `^` is applied third
4. `1 | 1           == 1`             - `|` is applied last

Comment: Except that `~0` is in python `-1`, because it flips "all" the bits, whatever that means for an arbitrary-sized integer.

Comment: @James Newman Thanks for the explanation. I have one more doubt so does the bitwise operators binding is from right to left then?

Comment: @JayantAgarwal The official documentation for the order of operations in python expressions is https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html , but among bitwise operators it's: first `~`, then `<<` and `>>` (left to right), then `&`, then `^`, then `|`.

Comment: @JayantAgarwal It does not read right to left. It's just like regular math where the precedence of certain operators are higher than others.

`2 + 3 * 2` for example is read as `2 + (3 * 2)` since the `*` operator has a higher precedence than `+`. You _effectively_ start from the right, but that's just because the rightmost statement `3 * 2` has higher precedence and happens to be on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first let's put some parentheses in that code to show how the order of operations applies in python:

```
print(1 | 0 ^ 1 & ~0)
```

becomes

```
print(1 | (0 ^ (1 & (~0))))
```

Okay, all good.

Now then, first we'll go through what `~0` means, then we'll consider what `1 & (~0)` is, then `0 ^ (1 & (~0))`, then `1 | (0 ^ (1 & (~0)))`.

Because these are all bitwise operations, I'm going to flip back and forth between decimal and binary without warning. I hope you've had a basic introduction to what binary is.

So, first `~0`. In languages with integer types that have a specific width, (e.g. in C or C++) `~0` would mean "a value that in binary is all `1` bits, as wide as the type", since `~` means "flip all the bits" and `0` is represented with all bits `0`. But since python's integers don't have a specific width that would mean "a value that in binary is an infinite sequence of `1` bits", and so we have to fall back on what it says in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations):

> The unary `~` (invert) operator yields the bitwise inversion of its integer argument. The bitwise inversion of `x` is defined as `-(x+1)`. It only applies to integral numbers or to custom objects that override the `__invert__()` special method.

So `~0` is `-1`.

Now, what's `1 & (-1)` ? Well, in binary `1` is just `1`, and `-1` is all `1` bits, as large as you might want. So the bitwise `&` of those two values is just `1`, since for bitwise `&` the output has a `1` bit only where both inputs have a `1` bit.

Now, `0 ^ (1)`. Well, we know what `0` looks like in binary, and we know what `1` looks like in binary (they look just like decimal), and with `^` the output has a `1` bit only where the output and input differ. So `0 ^ 1` is just `1`.

Now `1 | (1)`. This is just `1`, by the definition of `|`.

In a way, python makes reasoning this out harder than it would be in C or many other languages by not having a fixed size for its integers, so when dealing with `~0` you have to briefly imagine that there's this infinite string of `1`s that you're dealing with, but it isn't that bad.